# Merging 3 MySQL Databases with similar data but different ID's?

Tags: php, mysql, database

We're in the process of combining some separate company DB's that were set up at different stages, they all have roughly the same data, but not in the same order/ID's.

Here's a pseudo overlay of the 3 databases with 2 example tables of each:

`+------------+-----------+---------------+
| DATABASE 1 |           |               |
+------------+-----------+---------------+
| fruit_id   | name      |               |
| 1          | orange    |               |
| 2          | apple     |               |
| 3          | banana    |               |
|            |           |               |
| sales_id   | fruit_ids |               |
| 1924       | 2,3       | apple,banana  |
| 1925       | 1,3       | orange,apple  |
|            |           |               |
| DATABASE 2 |           |               |
| fruit_id   | name      |               |
| 1          | apple     |               |
| 2          | orange    |               |
| 3          | banana    |               |
|            |           |               |
| sales_id   | fruit_ids |               |
| 1924       | 2,3       | orange,banana |
| 1925       | 1,3       | apple,banana  |
|            |           |               |
| DATABASE 3 |           |               |
| fruit_id   | name      |               |
| 1          | banana    |               |
| 2          | apple     |               |
| 3          | orange    |               |
|            |           |               |
| sales_id   | fruit_ids |               |
| 1950       | 2,3       | apple,orange  |
| 1951       | 1,3       | banana,orange |
+------------+-----------+---------------+`

You'll see that some database sales_id are actually duplicated, and even fruit_ids relates to different items in each table.

The real databases we're working with will have fruit_ids dotted around the database in lots of places, and some of the databases contain 1m+ rows, so manual MySQL queries are sort of out of the picture.

The actual databases we need to combine have a much higher complexity than the above pseudo table, but I'm looking to see if there is any logic/tool/software that helps combine MySQL databases with this kind of similar data?

Comment: Why did you use different databases ?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48299/merge-multiple-tables-in-a-database < Maybe this can help you out?

Comment: I don't know what kind of complaxity in your data but you can start as first choose a database your primary db, then consider this db fruit_id your final fruit_id, then change all other db's fruit_id in sales tables as per your prmary db. now you can merge.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com - They were/are 3 separately trading companies that basically do the exact same thing setup by the same IT company.

Comment: Are foreign keys set up correctly in the database, with all the correct cascades? If so, it might be fairly easy to change IDs. If not, then you're looking at a really complex process. In either case, I'd suggest exporting all the data and putting it all in a completely new database.

Comment: Do all the id's have to match with the corresponding value? For instance orange has id's of 1,2 and 3. Can orange just have a single matching id after you combine?

Comment: @CesarBielich - Ideally after the merge, yes Orange should have an id of ~1

Answer (score 1):

Not much by way of answers so far. Here is some initial effort to show generating common keys between some number of databases having the same format:

```
// Source databases or companies
// -----------------------------
$corp = array();
$corp[0] = 'XYZ Corp';
$corp[1] = 'ABC Corp';
$corp[2] = '123 Corp';

// Source fruit lists
// ------------------
$fruit = array();

$fruit[0]['orange'] = 1;
$fruit[0]['apple']  = 2;
$fruit[0]['banana'] = 3;
$fruit[0]['kiwi']   = 4;

$fruit[1]['apple']  = 1;
$fruit[1]['orange'] = 2;
$fruit[1]['banana'] = 3;
$fruit[1]['pear']   = 4;

$fruit[2]['banana'] = 1;
$fruit[2]['apple']  = 2;
$fruit[2]['orange'] = 3;
$fruit[2]['grape']  = 4;

// Master fruit list
// -----------------
echo "Generating common fruit key list...<br>\n";

// Generate common keys in sorted item order
// -----------------------------------------
$common = array();
foreach ($corp as $corpid => $name)
{
  echo "<br>\n";
  echo "... examining fruit keys for " . $corp[$corpid] . "<br>\n";
  foreach ($fruit[$corpid] as $name => $id)
  {
    $common[$name] = 0;
    echo "... ... fruit $name has key $id<br>\n";
  }
}

ksort($common);

$i = 0;
foreach ($common as $name => $dummy )
   $common[$name] = ++$i;

echo "<br>\n";   
print_r($common);
echo "<br><br>\n";

// Demonstrate index conversions
// -----------------------------
echo "Demonstrating conversions to common indexes per company...<br>\n";

foreach ($corp as $corpid => $name)
{
  echo "<br>\n";
  echo "... examining key conversions for " . $corp[$corpid] . "<br>\n";
  foreach ($fruit[$corpid] as $name => $id)
  {
    $new = $common[$name];
    $old = $id;
    echo "... ... fruit $name key changes from $old to $new<br>\n";
  }
}
```

You'll get results similar to the following:

```
Generating common fruit key list...

... examining fruit keys for XYZ Corp
... ... fruit orange has key 1
... ... fruit apple has key 2
... ... fruit banana has key 3
... ... fruit kiwi has key 4

... examining fruit keys for ABC Corp
... ... fruit apple has key 1
... ... fruit orange has key 2
... ... fruit banana has key 3
... ... fruit pear has key 4

... examining fruit keys for 123 Corp
... ... fruit banana has key 1
... ... fruit apple has key 2
... ... fruit orange has key 3
... ... fruit grape has key 4

Array ( [apple] => 1 [banana] => 2 [grape] => 3 [kiwi] => 4 [orange] => 5 [pear] => 6 ) 

Demonstrating conversions to common indexes per company...

... examining key conversions for XYZ Corp
... ... fruit orange key changes from 1 to 5
... ... fruit apple key changes from 2 to 1
... ... fruit banana key changes from 3 to 2
... ... fruit kiwi key changes from 4 to 4

... examining key conversions for ABC Corp
... ... fruit apple key changes from 1 to 1
... ... fruit orange key changes from 2 to 5
... ... fruit banana key changes from 3 to 2
... ... fruit pear key changes from 4 to 6

... examining key conversions for 123 Corp
... ... fruit banana key changes from 1 to 2
... ... fruit apple key changes from 2 to 1
... ... fruit orange key changes from 3 to 5
... ... fruit grape key changes from 4 to 3
```

Some issues to consider:

- I don't think you can safely update tables in place as the keys will clash as provided above. If you wanted to you could avoid this by adjusting the new key values to not overlap with any existing key values. For example, in this case you could add an integer such as 100000 to all new common keys. This may allow an "in-place" update on prior key values -- perhaps useful for early testing or an alternate conversion path.
- You'll require a definitive list of tables to apply the conversions to. If the IDs are always using the same name this can be automated by scanning the database table formats (perhaps via describe tablename).
- If you really do have a comma seperated list of ID values in the database, as demonstrated, you'll have to do additional work to identify them all, parse them out and update all of them appropriately.
- You'll notice I added a unique inventory item to each company (i.e. kiwi, pear, grape) as there is a chance they may not all carry exactly the same product set.

This should provide a starting point for thinking about this. How long it might take to process all source databases into a new database and then validate the merged result is hard to say.